# Putting our logo in the Email Notifications that system sends out

Tags: oracle, image, email

We want to be able to show our logo, but it always comes out with "Download Image" prompt instead of showing the email in the body..

Emails are built using the Oracle Mail_pkg... How do I add the image to the HTML body so that it shows without a user having to download the image like it's an attachment? (also want to show it in blackberry)

I know it's possible since if you add an image to the outlook signature, you can see those pictures on outlook and blackberry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along with a nice answer sleske provided I can suggest you to create a message you want to look like in Outlook or elsewhere, take a look at the message source and try to reproduce it in Oracle.

Also bear in mind that using `utl_mail` package you can send messages with body only 4 000 chars long (the size of `varchar2` type in `SQL`). I can suggest you try `utl_smtp` package, though it requires a little more coding and accuracy, it gives you much more flexibility in creating fancy e-mails.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the image itself inside the email, usually as an attachment.

To have it show inside the email, you need to link to the attachment from inside your email. This is commonly done using the `cid` scheme.

See e.g. http://mailformat.dan.info/headers/mime.html for more information.

Or straight to the source:

[Content-ID and Message-ID Uniform Resource Locators](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2392)